# Check if date is between two dates in ArrayList using a while loop

Tags: java, date, arraylist, while-loop, calendar

I have the following `while` loop:

```
while (!inputDateCalendar.after(endYearCalendar) && !vacations.contains(newLesson.getDate())) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

`inputDateCalendar` and `endYearCalendar` are both of type `GregorianCalendar`.
`vacations` is an `ArrayList` which contains items of type `Vacation`.

```
public Vacation(String type, String region, Date startDate, Date endDate, int schoolYear)
{
    this.type = type;
    this.region = region;
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
    this.schoolYear = schoolYear;
}
```

`newLesson` is a `Lesson` object:

```
public class Lesson {

    private int id;
    private int studentID;
    private String student;
    private String type;
    private Time duration;
    private double price;
    private Date date;
    private Time time;

}
```

All of those are set.

Now I am trying to make sure the loop only does stuff while `inputDateCalendar` is not after `endYearCalendar` **and** `vacations` does not contain a date that is between the `startDate` and `endDate` of any `Vacation` in the list.

I know people will recommend Joda-time, but I would like to try it like this for now.

Comment: vacations is an ArrayList of Vacation objects and you are searching in contains by a Date type? What is newLesson?

Comment: And where is the problem?

Comment: it's Joda time library not Yoda

Comment: So, you'll need to make sure your vacation list is sorted, assuming there are no overlapping vacations, and you'll need to write a method to binary-search it based on a given date. `contains()` won't help you, it's used for looking up a particular vacation.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Mou it seems that you are having some Type problems - I think you have to traverse the vacations list and check the dates:

```
while(!inputDateCalendar.after(endYearCalendar)) {
    for(Vacation vacation : vacations) {
        if(newLesson.getDate().after(vacation.getStartDate()) && newLesson.getDate().before(vacation.getEndDate()))
            do.stuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: (a) OP wants to do stuff only when the lesson is **not** within any vacation. (b) Linear search is not very efficient.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this one after adding a ! so it will do what I want. I'll let you know if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can user `Collections2.filter`
Something like this should do the work.

```
private static class LessonPredicate implements Predicate<Vacation> {
    private Lesson lesson;
    public LessonPredicate(Lesson lesson) {
        this.lesson = lesson;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean apply(Vacation vacation) {
        return lesson.getDate().after(vacation.getStartDate()) && lesson.getDate().before(vacation.getEndDate())
    }
}

while(!inputDateCalendar.after(endYearCalendar) && !Collections2.filter(vacations, new LessonPredicate(newLesson)).isEmpty()) {
    do.stuff();
}
```

Comment: OP wants the `do.Stuff` to run only if the lesson is **not** in the vacation list. And this is linear search, which is nov very efficient.

Comment: Yes it not but no one is asking for more efficient approach.